# Symfony - parametrized ips in security.yml

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony-3.4

In my app I have api and admin access, I am trying to move allowed ips to parameters.yml
Composer stores array as:

```
api_allowed_ips:
    - 127.0.0.1
    - 192.168.0.1
```

Then in security.yml I do:

```
- { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: %api_allowed_ips% }
```

But it does not work, all IPs are let through. Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You should put %api_allowed_ips% inside quotes